# Binary tree in Prolog and leaves

Tags: tree, prolog, binary-tree

I'm very new to Prolog and we didn't have much theory about it. In the lectures we looked at basic stuff like atoms, variables, what a relation means etc.
But now I have a task I don't understand how to begin/how to solve.

We should create a relation `leaf(X,Y)` where `X` is a binary tree and `Y` an atom. The relation should be true if `Y` is a leaf of `X`. We can test if a variable `A` is a leaf by using `atom(A)`. Further it is important to note that `Y` should be an atom and not a subtree.

Examples:

```
?- leaf([x,[y,[z,v]]], v).
true

?- leaf([x,[y,[z,v]]], w).
false
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you've tried so far. [Edit] it into your question.

Comment: I literally have nothing because I don't really understand how "trees" work in Prolog. I only know Java and Python which are both really intuitive and kind of visual for me as a noob... I would already be happy if you maybe know a website or so which explains trees in prolog overall? I have really no startpoint yet to tackle my exercise...

Comment: Prolog doesn't really have trees... the exercise uses lists, whose members can be lists, whose members can be lists, whose members can be lists... The trees are implemented using lists. It's all about recursion. That is also how you should think for this exercise (and most Prolog problems): recursion. First question to ask yourself: what is the simplest case where you can determine if a node is a leaf? Second question to ask yourself: IF I can determine if L is a leaf of T, can I also determine if L is a leaf of its supertree? The key is recursion. Good luck!

Comment: oh, I didn't realise that! That really helped, thanks a lot!